# Show badges number in react-native's bottom tab navigation V5 with mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm new to react native and want to show badges with notification numbers in my react-native bottom tab navigator. I want something like the image bellow:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1215843/24154227/8cf55b04-0e8b-11e7-8ce5-30aa00527824.png

I use mobx for state management in my react-native app, in each store I would have a computed value for badge counts (number which appear inside the red badge icon).

```
import { observable, action, flow } from "mobx";

export class DiscoverStore
{
    @observable badgeCount = 0;
}
```

My bottom tabs component looks like this:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default TAB1 = () => {
    
    const { trendingStore, DiscoverStore } = useStores();
    
    return (
    <Tab.Navigator style={{ height:50 }}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        headerShown: true  ,     
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => 
        {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Trending') { iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'; }
            else if (route.name === 'Discover'){ iconName = focused ? 'crosshairs-gps' : 'crosshairs';}
            else if (route.name === 'Favorites'){ iconName = focused ?  'heart' : 'heart-outline';}
            else if (route.name === 'Profile'){ iconName = focused ? 'arrow-right-bold-box' : 'arrow-right-bold-box-outline' ;}

            return <Icon name={iconName} size={25} color='rgb(68,68,68)' style={{ marginTop:5 }}/>;
        },})}
        tabBarOptions={{
            keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
            activeTintColor: 'rgb(30,30,30)',
            inactiveTintColor: 'rgb(68,68,68)',
            //activeBackgroundColor:'',
            //inactiveBackgroundColor:'',
            style : { height:50 },
            tabStyle: { paddingVertical: 2, },
            labelStyle: 
            {
                fontSize: 12,
                margin: 0,
                padding: 0,
            },
        }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name="Trending" component={STACK1}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={STACK2}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={STACK3}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={STACK4}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
    );}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **tabBarBadge** navigation option of the screens:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={STACK2}  
options={{tabBarBadge:(DiscoverStore.badgeCount>0?DiscoverStore.badgeCount:null)}}/>
```

tabBarBadge in the React Navigation documentation:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#add-badges-to-icons